# Term frequency list of an entire search index?

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope, enterprise-search

I am trying to get the term frequency of all words in an index (minus some words like: a, the, and, I, etc.). A "Top 10" list of most frequent words in an index would be ideal.

I am not trying to get a search keyword frequency, rather an index term frequency.

Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible - and a solution would be very very complex. Think about problems like how to handle document full-text and the definition of a term.